# Android - Is it ok to register a reciever multiple times?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
//Gives current batterie temperature in celsius
public void  getBatteryTemperature()
{
    BroadcastReceiver BatterieTemperatureReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int batTemp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0)/10;
            //optional Log output for debug
            Log.i("batterietemperature", String.valueOf(batTemp) + "°C");
        }
    };
    this.getContext().registerReceiver(BatterieTemperatureReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

//Gives current batterie level in percent 
public void  getBatteryLevel()
{
    BroadcastReceiver BatterieLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int batLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
            //optional Log output for debug
            Log.i("BatterieLevel", "Level " + batLevel + "%");
        }
    };
    this.getContext().registerReceiver(BatterieLevelReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}
```

This methods get called in my Main, but while developing i asked myself if it is ok to register a reciever multiple times? Or will it maybe cause trouble? It feels a little bit bad to do something like this...
I hope questions like this are allowed here :)

Comment: Each time you call `getBatteryLevel` or `getBatteryTemperature` you create a new instance of the BroadcastReceiver; do you unregister your receivers with `unregisterReceiver `?
I prefer to have one instance of the broadcastreceiver, my advice is use a singleton class for your broadcastreceiver.

Comment: its fine, you can register for a broadcast any number of times you want. It won't cause any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you cannot join them together and create `BatteryInfoReceiver`, register it once and extract the temperature and amount of juice left at the same time.

Still, your approach seems fine. The overhead of calling two receivers is negligible, the amount of memory the system has to keep to remember two different receivers instead of one also in double digits, when measured in bytes.

Finally, if it works, I'd leave it be =)

Comment: Thank you guys!
That helped alot and maybe i unregister the reciever like Raul answered. Question can be closed as solved. Have a nice day to everyone!